# EF Core Power Tools : use identitiydbcontext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-power-tools

I have been using EF Core Power Tools to reverse engineer an existing SQL database. We are now at the stage where we wanted to implement identity, I have setup the `program.cs` with this code:

```
builder.Services
       .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectDbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

From what I read the `ProjectDbContext` should inherit from `IdentityDbContext`, not `DbContext`. Currently using EF Core Power Tools, it generates the `DbContext` as:

```
public partial class ProjectDbContext: DbContext
```

If I manually change that then the next time I build using Power Tools it will override it. Is there anyway to get that to work with `IdentityDbContext`? I've tried to add another partial class into the project:

```
public partial class ProjectDbContext: IdentityDbContext
```

but that causes the error:

> Partial declarations of 'ProjectDbContext' must not specify different base classes

Comment: You can set EF Core Powertools to only generate Models, when you synch.

Comment: @PoulBak yes you are correct, but then I need to also add the DbSet<> manually for each table, I was hoping there was a way to keep generating it and have a way to use IdentityDbContext.

Comment: Actually a good feature, you want, I suggest you give it to the developer.

Comment: Same situation here. Did you find a solution @Paritosh ?

Comment: @SylvainC. no, we ended up using a separate API for the Identity management portion so that one had it's own dbcontext which we used the IdentityDbContext.

Comment: Since you already have the ProjectDbContext and manually inherited from IdentityDbContext, try to refresh instead of edit on the efptcore.config.json file.